# Laravel 5.8 PDF upload

Tags: php, laravel-5

for my website I need a form which includes a file upload for PDF files, but I'm new to these and don't really know how to do it.

This is what I got so far, but keep getting:

> "Too few arguments to function `App\Http\Controllers\FileController::create()`, 0 passed and exactly 1 expected"

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Payment;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class FileController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){

        $users = User::all();
        return view('fileupload.create', compact('users'));
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $request = app('request');
        if($request->hasfile('file')){
            $file = $request->file('file');
            $filename = $file['filename']->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Storage::make($file)->save( public_path('/storage/loonstrookjes/' . $filename) );
            dd($filename);

        }


        return Payment::create([
            'file_name' => $filename,
            'file_path' => '/storage/loonstrookjes/',
            'user_id' => $data['employee'],
        ]);

        return route('fileupload.create');
    }

}
```

Model User:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Kyslik\ColumnSortable\Sortable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use Sortable;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Model Payment:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Payment extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'payment_list';

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'file_name', 'file_path'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'id', 'file_name', 'file_path'
    ];
}
```

View:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">{{ __('Loonstrook uploaden') }}</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('create') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            @csrf

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="filename" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Bestandsnaam') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="filename" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('filename') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="filename" value="{{ old('filename') }}" required autofocus>

                                    @if ($errors->has('filename'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('filename') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="file" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Bestand') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="file" type="file" class="form-control" name="file">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="usertype" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Werknemer:') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <select class="form-control" name="type">
                                        @foreach($users as $user)
                                        <option value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->first_name}} {{$user->last_name}}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        {{ __('Uploaden') }}
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

These are my routes:

```
Route::get('/create', 'FileController@index')->name('create'); 
Route::post('/create', 'FileController@create');
```

I hope someone can help me find out what's wrong or a better way to do this. Thank you in advance!!

EDIT:

Your answers have helped me quite a bit, but now I'm facing another issue...

The controller now looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Payment;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
UploadedFile::getMaxFilesize();

class FileController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){

        $users = User::all();
        return view('fileupload.create', compact('users'));
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'filename' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'file' => ['required', 'file'],
            'user_id' => ['required'],
        ]);
    }

    protected function create(Request $request)
    {
        $request = app('request');
        if($request->hasfile('file')){
            $file = $request->file('file');
            $filename = $request->input('filename');
            $file = $filename . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $file_path = storage_path('/loonstrookjes');
            Storage::disk('local')->putFile($file_path, new File($request->file), $file);
            //$path = $request->file('file')->store( storage_path('/storage/loonstrookjes/'));
            //$path = Storage::putFile(storage_path('/loonstrookjes/'), $filename);
            //dd($upload);

            //return $put;
        }

        return Payment::create([
            'file_name' => $filename,
            'file_path' => '/storage/loonstrookjes/',
            'user_id' => $request['user'],
        ]);

        return route('fileupload.create');
    }

}
```

But I'm getting a new error, this time it's:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::hashName()

Any ideas??

Comment: Where are you making the call to the `create` function of `FileController ` class?

Comment: that's the problem then. you say that your create function requires a parameter $data to work. Also why don't you make it a public function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you have a parameter in your method `create(array $data)`, but you are posting the form using only `{{ route('create') }}`. Here you are calling the method by this route without passing the required parameter as you defined it.

Basically, a form post method can accept the requested values by this

`protected function create(Request $request)`

Because you already used `Request` as a trait.

So, by this, you can get the requested field value from your form. And you don't have to use `$request = app('request');` since you already have it on the parameter variable `$request`.

> In case you want to know

Variables are passed from frontend (view) 
to the backend (route) by using `{{ route('update', $the_variable) }}`.

By this, you can have `$the_variable` after the last `/` of your route.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Route:

```
Route::resource('File','FileController');
```

Controller changes:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    { 

            if($request->hasfile('file')){
               $file = $request->file('file');
               $filename = $file['filename']->getClientOriginalExtension();
               Storage::make($file)->save( public_path('/storage/loonstrookjes/' . $filename) );  

            }

           return Payment::create([
              'file_name' => $filename,
              'file_path' => '/storage/loonstrookjes/',
              'user_id' => $request->type
           ]);

           return route('fileupload.create');
     }
 }
```

View Changes:

```
form action="{{ route('File.store') }}"
```

Comment: Route [store] not defined. (View: F:\xampp\htdocs\EmployeeDash\resources\views\fileupload\create.blade.php)is the new error

Comment: Sorry, Please check view file action. I have update view action.

Comment: If any query then comment. If work fine then please vote or ans as true...

Comment: I've updated the view to what you said and then I got the error